# How do I track a public repository/ organisation's progress on Github?

Tags: github, github-api

I want to track some projects hosted publicly on GitHub by others and export metrics such as the number of commits, pr merges, and issues resolved to a CSV document periodically.

I've read the GitHub docs to figure out a way to use the API to extract data, but as per my understanding, the API is for tracking projects hosted by the owner only. Any help?

Comment: APIs ("Application Programming Interfaces") are used by people who write applications; they do whatever they do. If they do what you need, that's fine. Note that Issues and PRs are GitHub-specific, not part of Git at all. (The commit count is obtainable through regular Git but you must clone and then later update the entire repository to do that.)

Comment: I know what APIs are, but that's not the point. I want to know if there is a way to obtain those metrics of other repositories using GitHub API. I know I can get the commit counts if I clone the repositories, but that's not feasible if there are more than a hundred repositories.

Comment: So what's your actual question then? "I tried this GitHub API on a repository I don't own and it worked, was that a fluke?" perhaps? Or "I tried this GitHub API on a repository I don't own and it didn't work; are there other APIs?" Either one would be a valid question about the GitHub APIs, though probably best directed *at* GitHub rather than at StackOverflow.

Comment: I don't own those repositories, but I want to track those. GitHub API doesn't have that functionality. Is there any other way?

Comment: Probably not. But you should show what APIs you have used, with what effects on repositories to which you do and don't have whatever access. Be as explicit and detailed as you can while at the same time presenting as little detail as required to describe the problem(s): see [ask] and [mre].